# How to create a Facebook page to submit a form to my website?

Tags: facebook

I have a website where my registered users can fill a form and submit their data to my website database. I also want a page on Facebook where my users can do this, without going to my website.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to open an application and then add it to your page as a tab, page tabs are simply iframes so it shouldn't be an issue to create one for a simple form.

You can get started on:
http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: This is exactly what I have done, but the POST data is not forwarded